# I want to create a command that will find the last deleted message in the channel and the bot will send the message that was deleted

Tags: python, discord.py

When someone sends the command .snipe the bot will respond with the last deleted message in the channel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While StackOverflow encourages you to ask away any questions you have, it is not a page that has people write your code for you.
Please provide any work that you have already done so that people are able to help you (by pointing out mistakes or suggesting changes / possible solutions for an actual problem).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all verified bots have removed snipe command as it is against discord TOS. Bots such as Dank Memer have removed that command, many more too.

So I recommend not to add a snipe command, but if you are using it for private purposes, here it is -

```
#lists
client.sniped_messages = {}

#events
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)

#command
@client.command()
async def snipe(ctx):
    try:
        contents, author, channel_name, time = client.sniped_messages[ctx.guild.id]
        
    except:
        await ctx.channel.send("Couldn't find a message to snipe!")
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(description=contents, color=discord.Color.purple(), timestamp=time)
    embed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}#{author.discriminator}", icon_url=author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Deleted in : #{channel_name}")

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Hope this helped! Please approve my answer if it did help you.

Comment: It is not against ToS. Dank memer still has snipe command.

Comment: Yea, the recently added again. Thanks for informing.